# SOLVED OSError: [Errno 5] EIO wit a raspberry pi pico

Tags: hardware, pi-pico

I am using the Raspberry Pi Pico with this code:

```
#Pico Invaders!
#
# TODO : Implement alien shots, Shields, Sound
from machine import Pin, I2C, ADC, PWM
from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C
import time 
import framebuf
import random
time.sleep(2)
WIDTH  = 128                                            # oled display width
HEIGHT = 64                                             # oled display height

Pot = ADC(26)
conversion_factor = 3.3 / (65535) # Conversion from Pin read to proper voltage

speaker = PWM(Pin(18))

i2c = I2C(0)                                            # Init I2C using I2C0 defaults, SCL=Pin(GP9), SDA=Pin(GP8), freq=400000


oled = SSD1306_I2C(WIDTH, HEIGHT, i2c)                  # Init oled display

lowres = True

if lowres == True:
    #smaller alien sprites. set spritex to 5 and spritey to 5
    inv1a = bytearray(b"\xd0xPx\xf0")
    inv1b = bytearray(b"\xf0xPx\xd0")
    inv2a = bytearray(b"\xe0P\xf8P\xe0")
    inv2b = bytearray(b"\xd0x\xd0")
    spritex = 5 #how big are your alien sprites?
    spritey = 5
    aliencountx = 4 #How many rows and columns of aliens
    aliencounty = 5
    alienspacingx = 5
    alienspacingy = 3
else:
     #sprite definitions for Aliens. set spritex and spritey to 7
    inv1a = bytearray(b"~\xd8\x88\xf8\x88\xd8~")
    inv1b = bytearray(b"|\xda\xc8\xf8\xc8\xda|")
    inv2a = bytearray(b"\x88\\:\x1e:\\\x88")
    inv2b = bytearray(b"\x08\\\xba\x1e\xba\\\x08")
    spritex = 7 #how big are your alien sprites?
    spritey = 7
    aliencountx = 4 #How many rows and columns of aliens
    aliencounty = 4
    alienspacingx = 3
    alienspacingy = 3
logo = bytearray(b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\xff\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\xff\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\xff\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xbd\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xbd\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xbd\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x01\xff\x80\x00\x07\xbd\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x01\xff\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x08\x80\x00\x00\x01\xef\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x01\x08\x80\x00\x00\x01\xef\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xfc\x07\xff\xe0\x01\x08\x80\x00\x00\x01\xef\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xfc\x07\xff\xe0\x01\x08\x80\x00\x00\x01\xef\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xff\xe0\x01\xff\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x008\xe0\x00\xf7\x00\x00\x07\xbd\xefx\x1e\x00\x02\xff\x00\x00\x18\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xbd\xefx\x1e\x00?\xff\x00\x00?\xe0\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x07\xbd\xefx\x1e\x00?\xd0\x00\x00\x1f\xc0\x08<\x00\x00\x07\xbd\xefx\x1e\x00<\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x80\x0c\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xc0\x00\x00\xf0=\xe0{\xc0\x00?\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xc0\x00\x00\xf0=\xe0{\xc0\x00\x00\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x00\x00\xf0=\xe0{\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00<\x00\x00\xf0=\xe0{\xc0\x00\x00`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x7f\xc0\x07\xff\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0=\xefx\x00\x00\x00\x7f\xfe\x07\xff\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0=\xefx\x00\x00\x00\x1e\xfe\x07\xff\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0=\xefx\x00\x00\x00\x18\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0=\xefx\x00\x00\x00?\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x7f\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x01\xff\x80\x00\x00=\xefx\x00\x00\x00\x7f\x80\x00\x00\x00\x01\xff\x80\x00\x00=\xefx\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x80\x00\x00=\xefx\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x80\x00\x00=\xefx\x00\x00?\xff\x00\x01\xff\x80\x00\x10\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\xff\x00\x03\xff\xc0\x00\x10\x80\x00\xf0=\xefx\x00\x00?\xff\x00\x07\xff\xe0\x00\x1f\x80\x00\xf0=\xefx\x00\x008\x07\x00\x07\x00\xe0\x00\x0f\x00\x00\xf0=\xefx\x00\x000'\x00\x06\x00\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0=\xefx\x00\x00?\xff\x00\x07\xe7\xe0\x01\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\xfe\x00\x03\xe3\xc0\x01\xfc\x00\x00\xf0=\xe0{\xc0\x00\x0f\xfc\x00\x01\xe3\x80\x00\x04\x00\x00\xf0=\xe0{\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\xf0=\xe0{\xc0\x00\x00\x7f\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x01\xfc\x00\x00\xf0=\xe0{\xc0\x00\x00\x7f\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x01\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x7f\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xbd\xefx\x1e\x00\x00q\xce\x01\xff\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xbd\xefx\x1e\x00\x00`\xc6\x03\xff\xc0\x01\xff\x80\x00\x07\xbd\xefx\x1e\x00\x00p\x8e\x07\xff\xe0\x01\xff\x80\x00\x07\xbd\xefx\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\xe0\x00\x10\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xfc\x00\x06\x04\xe0\x00\x10\x80\x00\x00\x01\xef\x00\x00\x00\xff\xfc\x00\x07\xff\xe0\x00\x10\x80\x00\x00\x01\xef\x00\x00\x00\xff\xfc\x00\x03\xff\xc0\x00\x10\x80\x00\x00\x01\xef\x00\x00\x00\x03\x9c\x00\x01\xff\x80\x00\x1f\x80\x00\x00\x01\xef\x00\x00\x00\t\x9c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xbd\xe0\x00\x00\x00\xfe\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xbd\xe0\x00\x00\x00\xfep\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xbd\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xbd\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1cx\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00<\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00|\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q\xce\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x7f\xde\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x9c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x18\x00\x00\x00")

ship = bytearray(b" p\xf8l>//>l\xf8p ")
ufo = bytearray(b"\x0c\x00>\x80\x1d\x80\r\xe0\x1d\xc0\x15\x80>\x80\x0c\x00")

num0 = bytearray(b"\x7f\x80\xff\xc0\x80@\x80@\xff\xc0\x7f\x80")
num1 = bytearray(b"\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x80\xff\xc0\xff\xc0\x00\x00")
num2 = bytearray(b"\xe1\x80\xf1\xc0\x98@\x8c@\x87\xc0\x83\x80")
num3 = bytearray(b"@\x80\xc0\xc0\x84@\x84@\xff\xc0{\x80")
num4 = bytearray(b"0\x00<\x00/\x00#\x80\xff\xc0\xff\xc0")
num5 = bytearray(b"O\xc0\xcf\xc0\x84@\x84@\xfc@x@")
num6 = bytearray(b"\x7f\x80\xff\xc0\x84@\x84@\xfc\xc0x\x80")
num7 = bytearray(b"\x00@\xe0@\xfc@\x1f@\x03\xc0\x00\xc0")
num8 = bytearray(b"{\x80\xff\xc0\x84@\x84@\xff\xc0{\x80")
num9 = bytearray(b"G\x80\xcf\xc0\x88@\x88@\xff\xc0\x7f\x80")

aliens = []
class Alien(object):
    
    def __init__(self, type, x, y):
        self.visible = True
        self.type = type
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.origx = x
        self.origy = y
    
def create_alien(type, x, y):
    alien = Alien(type, x, y)
    return alien

def define_aliens():
    type = "inv1a" #First row is type 1. 
    for x in range (1, aliencountx + 1):
        for y in range (1, aliencounty + 1):
            aliens.append(create_alien(type, (120 - ((x * (spritex + alienspacingx)) - spritex)), (y * (spritey + alienspacingy)) - spritey))
        if type == "inv1a":
            type = "inv2a" #Second row is type 2
        else:
            type = "inv1a"

def reset_aliens(visibility): # Used to reset aliens to starting position and, optionally, visibility
    x = 1
    y = 1
    for c in aliens:
        if visibility:
            c.visible = True
            
        c.x = c.origx
        c.y = c.origy
            
# Load images into framebuffer
inv1aBuff = framebuf.FrameBuffer(inv1a, 7, 7, framebuf.MONO_HLSB)
inv1bBuff = framebuf.FrameBuffer(inv1b, 7, 7, framebuf.MONO_HLSB)
inv2aBuff = framebuf.FrameBuffer(inv2a, 7, 7, framebuf.MONO_HLSB)
inv2bBuff = framebuf.FrameBuffer(inv2b, 7, 7, framebuf.MONO_HLSB)

ufoBuff = framebuf.FrameBuffer(ufo, 12, 8, framebuf.MONO_HLSB)

logoBuff = framebuf.FrameBuffer(logo, 128, 64, framebuf.MONO_HLSB)

#Dictionary for lookup of digits for score, level, possibly lives
numbers = {
    '0': framebuf.FrameBuffer(num0, 10, 6, framebuf.MONO_HLSB),
    '1': framebuf.FrameBuffer(num1, 10, 6, framebuf.MONO_HLSB),
    '2': framebuf.FrameBuffer(num2, 10, 6, framebuf.MONO_HLSB),
    '3': framebuf.FrameBuffer(num3, 10, 6, framebuf.MONO_HLSB),
    '4': framebuf.FrameBuffer(num4, 10, 6, framebuf.MONO_HLSB),
    '5': framebuf.FrameBuffer(num5, 10, 6, framebuf.MONO_HLSB),
    '6': framebuf.FrameBuffer(num6, 10, 6, framebuf.MONO_HLSB),
    '7': framebuf.FrameBuffer(num7, 10, 6, framebuf.MONO_HLSB),
    '8': framebuf.FrameBuffer(num8, 10, 6, framebuf.MONO_HLSB),
    '9': framebuf.FrameBuffer(num9, 10, 6, framebuf.MONO_HLSB)}

shipBuff = framebuf.FrameBuffer(ship, 8, 12, framebuf.MONO_HLSB)
# Clear the oled display in case it has junk on it.
oled.fill(0)
oled.blit(logoBuff, 0, 0)

# Finally update the oled display so the image & text is displayed
oled.show()

sleep(2)

addy = 3 #pixels of movement per turn on aliens

shotx = 1 
shoty = 1
loopCount = 0
define_aliens()
score = 0
difficulty = 1
showufo = False
ufoy = 0
ufoCount = 0
soundfreq = 160
while True:
    if showufo:
        if soundfreq == 1100: soundfreq = 2000
        else: soundfreq = 1100
        speaker.freq(soundfreq)
        speaker.duty_u16(2000)
    if shotx > 36 and showufo == False: speaker.duty_u16(0)
    ufoChance = random.randrange(1, 350, 1) # 1 in 1000 chance of running this loop that UFO will appear
    if ufoChance == 123 and showufo == False:
        showufo = True
        ufoy = 0
    if showufo:
        ufoy = ufoy + 1
        if ufoy > 64:
            showufo = False
    loopCount = loopCount + 1
    oled.fill(0)
    if loopCount > 16 - difficulty:
        if showufo == False:
            if soundfreq == 180: soundfreq = 160
            elif soundfreq == 160: soundfreq = 140
            elif soundfreq == 140: soundfreq = 120
            else: soundfreq = 180
            speaker.freq(soundfreq)
            speaker.duty_u16(2000)
         
        dropdown = False
        loopCount = 0
        for c in aliens:
            if c.visible == True: #switch between sprites to animate aliens
                if c.type == "inv1a": c.type = "inv1b"
                elif c.type == "inv1b": c.type = "inv1a"
                elif c.type == "inv2a": c.type = "inv2b"
                elif c.type =="inv2b": c.type = "inv2a"
                if c.y + addy > 56 or c.y + addy < 0: #are any of the visible invaders at the edge of the screen?
                    if c.x - 3 < 20: #If they're at the bottom, reset their position
                        reset_aliens(False)
                        dropdown = False
                    dropdown = True
        if dropdown == True: #move the aliens down if any of the visible ones hit the screen edge
            addy = addy * -1
            for c in aliens:
                c.x = c.x - 3 
        else:
            for c in aliens:
                c.y = c.y + addy
                
    shippos = (Pot.read_u16() * conversion_factor) #Read potentiometer to get ship position
    shippos = (64 - ((52 / 3.3) * shippos) - 12)
    shotx = shotx + 2
    foundVisible = False #By default, assume all the aliens are dead
    if showufo:
        if shotx > 120:
            if shoty >= ufoy:
                if shoty < ufoy + 12:
                    score = score + 50
                    showufo = False
                    ufoy = 0
                    shotx = 20
                    shoty = int(shippos) + 6
                    
    for c in aliens:
        if shotx >= c.x and c.visible == True: #Collision detection for aliens with the shots
            if shotx - 4 <= c.x + 8:
                if shoty > c.y:
                    if shoty <= c.y + 7: #You hit an alien!
                        c.visible = False 
                        score = score + 10
                        shotx = 32
                        shoty = int(shippos) + 6
        if c.visible == True:
            foundVisible = True
            if c.type == "inv1a": #Display aliens
                oled.blit(inv1aBuff, c.x, c.y) #display animation frame 1, set to frame 2 for next time
            elif c.type == "inv1b":
                oled.blit(inv1bBuff, c.x, c.y) #display animation frame 2, set to frame 1 for next time
            elif c.type == "inv2a":
                oled.blit(inv2aBuff, c.x, c.y) #display animation frame 1, set to frame 2 for next time
            elif c.type == "inv2b":
                oled.blit(inv2bBuff, c.x, c.y) #display animation frame 2, set to frame 1 for next time
        if showufo:
            oled.blit(ufoBuff, 120, ufoy)
    if shotx > 130:

        shotx = 32
        shoty = int(shippos) + 9
  
    if foundVisible == False: # You finish the level! Increase the difficulty and reset the aliens
            if difficulty < 10:
                difficulty = difficulty + 1
            reset_aliens(True)
    
    oled.blit(shipBuff, 18, int(shippos)) # draw the ship
    oled.line(shotx, shoty, shotx - 4, shoty, 1) #draw the laser
    
    numcount = 0 #keeps track of the number of times through the loop!
    
    for c in str(score):
        oled.blit(numbers[c], 1, ((numcount * 7) + 2)) #Display the score, 1 digit at a time
        numcount = numcount + 1
    
    numcount = 0
    
    for c in str(difficulty):
        oled.blit(numbers[c], 1, 48 + ((numcount * 7) + 2)) #Display the level, 1 digit at a time
        numcount = numcount + 1
                  
    oled.show()
    if shotx == 32 and showufo == False:
        speaker.duty_u16(0)
        speaker.freq(1000)
        speaker.duty_u16(2000)
    
    sleep(0.001)
```

It returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 21, in <module>
  File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 110, in __init__
  File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 71, in init_display
  File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 115, in write_cmd
OSError: [Errno 5] EIO
```

I have checked and double checked my wires and I even tried using different wires and nothing works.
Any suggestions?

Comment: We need clear photos of the connections used for that code.  We need to be able to see which Pico pin is connected to which OLED pin.  We need to also be able to see the OLED pin labelling.

Comment: Thats ok. I figured it out in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error as well, turned out to be my wiring.
My next problem that has came up when i tried to run the Alien_inv code was

MPY: soft reboot
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 100, in 
ValueError:

was this something you've come across?
Thanks!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/134078)